# ssh wget download jdk

Tags: ssh, wget

I've SSHed into one of my VPS and I'm trying to install java on it. Not really sure how to go about downloading but I am trying to use wget to download and install JDK7 from the Oracle website.

this file in particular: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u40-b43/jdk-7u40-linux-x64.rpm

To download the file, it requires authentication and I don't know how to do that through wget.

SOmeone please help

Comment: By authentication, do you mean the need to accept the license agreement? That's done with inline javascript and sets a series of cookies. You could create a cookies.txt file and use the --cookies-load option in wget, but I fear it may just be easier to download the file with your web browser and then do a sftp put to the VPS.

Answer (score 1):

```
# rpm
wget --no-cookies \
--no-check-certificate \
--header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" \
"http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u55-b13/jdk-7u55-linux-x64.rpm" \
-O jdk-7-linux-x64.rpm

# ubuntu
wget --no-cookies \
--no-check-certificate \
--header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" \
"http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u55-b13/jdk-7u55-linux-x64.tar.gz" \
-O jdk-7-linux-x64.tar.gz
# then
tar -xzvf jdk-7-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

refer: https://gist.github.com/scottvrosenthal/11187116

Answer (score 0):

> To download the file, it requires authentication and I don't know how
>   to do that through wget.

To be more accurate it requires license agreement.

If you have SSH access to the server you can copy file using `scp` command

```
scp /<path to the file>/jdk-7u40-linux-x64.rpm user-name@server-name:/tmp/
```

Then you go to the server by ssh and find it in /tmp/ folder